# Unable modify PDF Producer with ghostscript pdfmark

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

i want change producer at pdf info with ghostscript. i have put the producer name at pdfmarks file but after run command pdf still "GPL Ghostscript" at producer .
here my pdfmark file

```
[ /Title (Document title)
  /Author (Author name)
  /Subject (Subject description)
  /Keywords (comma, separated, keywords)
  /Creator (application name or creator note)
  /Producer (the name of producer pdf file)
  /DOCINFO pdfmark
```

this my command

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf pdfmark
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @KJ its helpfull, that mean we can make producer our own if we as writer. and we cant update the producer.

Comment: The AGPL version of Ghostscript's pdfwrite device specifically does not permit you to change the Producer using a pdfmark. As K J says, it would be wrong to do so as the Producer is Ghostscript. It is also useful to know that information when debugging problems and finally it prevents free users from trivially passing Ghostscript off as their own software.